# scale node js docker-haproy-socket.io-vue

Tags: docker, scale, haproxy

what I want to do is scale simple chat application. (frontend-vue-socket.io-client, backend-nodejs-redis-adapter-socket.io, load balancer-haproxy). it is working. But when I add second container back2 with image backnode, it is not working and there is no error code. Thanks to you, have a nice day.

[image: haproxy.cfg]

[image: docker-compose.yml]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :))
1- I run one container,
2- while the first socket connection continue, I run second container. And then I saw the socket keep reconnecting.( socketdID connected, socketID disconnected, and then go on ... )

and solution is, on client side, make the socket, disable long polling with transports config.

this.socket=io("http://localhost:9999",{
transports:['websocket']